# jquery sortable saving to database not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm trying to incorporate the jquery sortable functionality into my website and saving the positions in the database is giving me all sorts of headaches... I've been fighting this for 3 days now, and I cannot seem to get this work properly.

As it stands, it is saving positions to the database, but not in the order or positions, that you'd expect. Meaning, if I move the item in position 0 to position 1, it saves the positions in a different order in the db. check out a live version [here](http://simetriastudio.com/sorting/).

Here is my code...

index.php file:

```
<div id="container">
   <?php
      require_once 'conn.php';
      $q = ' SELECT * FROM items WHERE groupId = 3 ORDER BY position ';
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $q);
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         while($items = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      ?>
      <div id='sort_<?php echo$items['position'] ?>' class='items'>
         <span>&#9776;</span> <?php echo$items['description'] ?>
      </div>
      <?php
         }
      }
   ?>
</div>
```

js.js file:

```
$("#container").sortable({
   opacity: 0.325,
   tolerance: 'pointer',
   cursor: 'move',
   update: function(event, ui) {
      var itId = 3;
      var post = $(this).sortable('serialize');

      $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'save.php',
         data: {positions: post, id: itId },
         dataType: 'json',
         cache: false,
         success: function(output) {
            // console.log('success -> ' + output);
         },
         error: function(output) {
            // console.log('fail -> ' + output);
         }
      });

   }
});
$("#container").disableSelection();
```

save.php file:

```
require_once('conn.php');

$itId = $_POST['id'];
$orderArr = $_POST['positions'];
$arr = array();
$orderArr = parse_str($orderArr, $arr);
$combine = implode(', ', $arr['sort']);

$getIds = "SELECT id FROM items WHERE groupId = '$itId' ";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $getIds);

foreach($arr['sort'] as $a) {
   $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
   $sql = " UPDATE items
            SET position = '$a'
            WHERE id = '{$row['id']}' ";
   mysqli_query($db, $sql);
}

echo json_encode( ($arr['sort']) );
```

Can anyone please point to where I am going wrong on this?

Thank you in advance.

Serge

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either the [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) drivers. [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: Take a look at the **serialize** function, ("serialize the key") http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-serialize or ("toArray") http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-toArray. And take care at SQL injection.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I understand Alex. I'm just trying to get this working before moving on to security. There's absolutely nothing in that databse except this example.

Comment: @Richard I have also tried adding the key in the serialize function... not any better results. And as I mentioned to Alex,  I'm just trying to get this working before moving on to security. There's absolutely nothing in that databse except this example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone lands on here, here is what worked in my case...

**NOTE:** I did not create prepared statements in the index.php select function. But you probably should.

index.php file:

```
<div id="container">
      <?php
         require_once 'conn.php';
         $q = ' SELECT * FROM items WHERE groupId = 3 ORDER BY position ';
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $q);

         if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

            while( $items = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
      ?>
               <div id='sort_<?php echo $items['id'] ?>' class='items'>
                  <span>&#9776;</span> <?php echo $items['description'] ?>
               </div>
      <?php
            }
         }
      ?>
   </div>
```

jquery sortable file:

```
var ul_sortable = $('#container');

   ul_sortable.sortable({
      opacity: 0.325,
      tolerance: 'pointer',
      cursor: 'move',
      update: function(event, ui) {
         var post = ul_sortable.sortable('serialize');

         $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'save.php',
            data: post,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(output) {
               console.log('success -> ' + output);
            },
            error: function(output) {
               console.log('fail -> ' + output);
            }
         });

      }
   });
   ul_sortable.disableSelection();
```

update php file:

```
$isNum = false;

foreach( $_POST['sort'] as $key => $value ) {
    if ( ctype_digit($value) ) {
        $isNum = true;
    } else {
        $isNum = false;
    }
}

if( isset($_POST) && $isNum == true ){
    require_once('conn.php');
   $orderArr = $_POST['sort'];
    $order = 0;
    if ($stmt = $db->prepare(" UPDATE items SET position = ? WHERE id=? ")) {
        foreach ( $orderArr as $item) {
            $stmt->bind_param("ii", $order, $item);
            $stmt->execute();
            $order++;
        }
        $stmt->close();
    }
    echo json_encode(  $orderArr );
    $db->close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your JS code like this:

```
{...}
   tolerance: 'pointer',
   cursor: 'move',
// new LINE
   items: '.items', // <---- this is the new line
   update: function(event, ui) {
      var itId = 3;
      var post = $(this).sortable('serialize'); // it could be removed
// new LINES start
      var post={},count=0;
      $(this).children('.items').each(function(){
       post[++count]=$(this).attr('id');
      });
// new LINES end
      $.ajax({
{...}
```

With this `$.each` loop you overwrite your `var post -> serialize` and define your own sort order. Now look at your $_POST["positions"] with PHP `print_r($_POST["positions"]);` and you have your positions in your own order.

Comment: I've made the changes, but still nothing. still behaving erratic in terms of saving the data to the db

Comment: any other ideas as to why this is saving their order correctly. still fighting this issue.